# how to sort datagridview by displaymember and not by valuemember

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

this is the content of table 1

> Code,Description
>    1,Pineapple
>    2,Banana
>    3,Strawberry
>    4,Papaya
>    5,Apple

and it is binded to my datagridview.
I want to sort it by its displaymember and not by valuemember, so it will sort like this

> Code,Description
>    5,Apple
>  
>    2,Banana
>    4,Papaya
>    1,Pineapple
>    3,Strawberry

note: Description is only display to my datagridview and not the code field.

EDIT:

this is my code:

```
dim dgvColCmb as New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
with dgvColCmb
   tmpDSet.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = tmpDSet.Tables(0).Columns(1).ColumnName & " DESC "
   Dim tmpDTable As DataTable = tmpDSet.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable
   .DataSource = tmpDTable
   .ValueMember = tmpDTable.Columns(0).ColumnName
   .DisplayMember = tmpDTable.Columns(1).ColumnName
   .ReadOnly = True
end with
dtg.columns.add(dgvColCmb)
dtg.DataSource = sDSet.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the DataTable that is binded to the datagridview:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "Description desc";
DataTable sortedData = table.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: then...when I click the header of my datagridview..will it sort by displaymember?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `DataTable` in a [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx), then setting the Sort property of the DataView to the correct column. You would use the DataView as the DataSource, rather than the DataTable. Like so:

```vb
Dim l_view As New DataView(sDSet.Tables(0))
l_view.Sort = "Description" ' ...or... "Description DESC"
dtg.DataSource = l_view
```

Comment: Please define "it" in this context. Will the Sort save? When you edit the Sort?

Comment: i mean, when i sort the table (asc/desc) and edit some data then when i hit the button...will the record save?

Comment: A DataView is editable, so I would expect it to. Nothing better than trying it, though. (It will not save to the database - but I think you know that)